# C nested structs with list

Tags: c

I created structer of 10 by 10 array for storing random number. Also made a list so each member will hold different 10 by 10. But when i print it, the numbers kind of broken, i dont know if my for loops are incorrect or there is something else. I hope i am doing the list thing correct.

```
struct Num
{
    int Numbers[10][10];

};

struct Hold
{
    struct Num *List;
}FullList;


int main(void)
{
    time_t t;
    int x;
    srand((unsigned) time(&t));
    printf("Enter the number of arrays you want to create: ");
    scanf("%d", &x);

    FullList.List = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
    if (FullList.List == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Malloc failed.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    int i, j, k;


    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<10;k++)
            {
                FullList.List[i].Numbers[j][k] = rand() % 255;

            }


        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<x;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<10;j++)
        {
            for(k=0;k<10;k++)
            {

                printf("%d  %d  %d  %d %d  %d  %d  %d  %d  %d \n", FullList.List[i].Numbers[j][k]);

            }


        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `ImageList.List = malloc(x * sizeof(int));` is wrong.  It should be `ImageList.List = malloc(x * sizeof(struct Num));`  The amount you're allocating is *way* too small.  Also, you should check the value returned by `malloc` to make sure it isn't `NULL`.

Comment: @TomKarzes what do you mean by too small, how should i allocate then. Thanks for the answer btw

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/), for Stack Exchange to distribute that content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By Stack Exchange policy, the non-vandalized version of the post is the one which is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post please see: [How does deleting work?](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221)

Comment: @Carl It looks like someone gave you an answer, but the point is you were allocating space for `x` integers, but you needed space for `x` instances of `struct Num`.  Each `struct Num` contains an array of 100 integers total.  So the allocated size was 100 times too small at the very least.  This is something you really need to understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to assume `ImageList` is a typo and you meant `FullList`, which is what I'll use in my examples.  If that's the case, then you're not allocating memory correctly:

```
FullList.List = malloc(x * sizeof(int));
```

You're allocating enough space for `x` `int` objects, not `x` objects of type `struct Num`.  You're not allocating anywhere *near* enough space for your intended use.  A better way to do this would be

```
FullList.List = malloc( x * sizeof *FullList.List )
```

The expression `sizeof *FullList.List` is equivalent to `sizeof (struct Num)`; this will allocate enough space for `x` `struct Num` objects, which is what you want.  In general, you should write your `malloc` calls as

```
T *p = malloc( sizeof *p * N ); // for any non-function type T
```

or

```
T *p = NULL;
...
p = malloc( sizeof *p * N );
```

Always check the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc` calls.

Comment: thanks man helped a lot but the printed numbers are still wrong, this is the first line of the matris "28  0  9  6422048 0  6422048  4200281  1  34  -1230284480" no idea where those numbers came from.

Comment: The printf statement has lots of format specifiers (%d) but only provides one parameter to print (FullList.List[i].Numbers[j][k]).  The rest of the %d are getting undefined behavior, so just printing random values on the stack.  You want your print to have just one %d based on how you wrote the loops.

Comment: @OutrageousBacon ohh how did i missed that thanks man.